# Cannot rebind JHipsterProperties properties with Spring Cloud ContextRefresher

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud

I have a piece of code to do automatic configuration properties reloading in my JHipster application.
A lot of @ConfigurationProperties annotated beans are well refreshed except JHipsterProperties bean that is not.

The JHipsterProperties bean is not known by Sring Cloud Context's ConfigurationPropertiesBeans and I cannot understand why.

A solution is to add the missing @ConfigurationProperties beans to ConfigurationPropertiesBeans but this is just an ugly workaround.

```
public void triggerReload() throws IOException {
    LOG.info("Reloading configuration");

    try {
        this.contextRefresher.refresh();
    } catch (final BeanCreationException e) {
        // DO SOMETHING USEFUL
    }

    LOG.info(this.jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom()); // <--- value is not updated
    LOG.info(this.mailProperties.getHost()); // <--- value is updated
}
```